# Assigning a DataTable to SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, devexpress

I’ve got a custom Data access layer in my ASP.NET project. It goes to the db and retrieves all data required and returns it as DataTable objects. 
I want to bind one of the DataTables to DevExpress ComboBox control:

```
var productsDal = DalProviderFactory.Instance.GetProductsDal();
cbProducts.DataSource = productsDal.GetAllProductNames(); //--> One-column DataTable object is returned here.
cbProducts.DataMember = "ProductName"; //--> Specifying name of the column.
cbProducts.DataBind();
```

This doesn’t work; it definitely binds something but doesn’t display it properly:

[image]

Ok. I found out that the ComboBox actually accepts SqlDataSource object as its DataSource. So I’ce tried to configure one:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsProducts" runat="server" />
```

Now instead of having it connecting to the db itself, I want to use my DAL and somehow assign the datatable to the SqlDataSource. Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bashir,

use the `TextField` property of ASPxComboBox:

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox runat="server" TextField="HERE" />
```

Comment: I always wonder why DevExpress developers change standard names to something completely misleading :(. It is like this in WinForms controls (one particular thing that drives me crazy – when you need to use Hidden instead of Visible for visual controls) and now I see exactly the same stuff in WebForms. :(
Anyway thank you very much! Spasibo! :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `DisplayMember` should fix the problem.

Comment: There is no DisplayMember property in ASPxComboBox class